# Can I forbid my cocoapods update a specific library? because I want to change it's source code

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is there some commands in Podfile like `:forbid` or `:no-update`? I just don't want to update some specific libraries. And I don't want to add this library by myself.

Comment: Not sure, but I doubt it.  Fork the project instead and install via other means.

Comment: You can pod specific versions or specific commit hashes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should probably fork the library or use a local downloaded copy with the `:path` attribute in your Podfile.